# error ";overflow6" when running a VB6 application on Windows 2003 Server

Tags: vb6, windows-server-2003, overflowexception

I am running a VB6 application on Windows 2003 Server.
When I am running it, it is giving **;overflow6** error.

Can any one tell me why is so?

Comment: You might want to post the application, or the critical part of the source code so we can see what is likely to be the part going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

1. You are making a division and both num and denum are 0
2. You try to assign a bigger type to a smaller one (like Byte b = a Long value)
3. You multiply numbers and the result gets too big.

Check for divisions and if your data types are big enough to hold result of operations